# Table column width when having rowspan and table-layout fixe

Tags: css, html-table, width

I'm stuck with fixing the width of the second column of my html table.

Below is a printscreen of my table:

[image: Table Image]

Below is the CSS code:

```
#RevenueMTable tbody, #RevenueMTable thead {
display: block; 
}

#RevenueMTable {
    width: 1115px;
    table-layout: fixed !important;
}

#RevenueMTable tbody td:first-child
{
    width: 138px !important;
}

#RevenueMTable tbody td:not(:first-child)
{  
    width: 72px !important;

}

#RevenueMTable tbody
{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 400px;

}
```

The problem is that my first column has a rowspan of 4 rows. Therefore, for example the cell containing "COST" is the first TD element in the row tag and therefore is applied as well a width of 138px, although it should be seen as the second column.

[image: Table HTML code]

How can I fix this?

I tried applying column definition width as follows, but does not work either:

```
 $( '<col style="width:138px"><col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px"> <col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px"><col style="width:72px">').insertBefore( $("#RevenueMTable thead") )
```

Comment: could you please provide the HTML also for faster resolution, if possible a jsfiddle highlighting the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have classes on your TD elements. You can target the column directly using those. I changed the order of the rules so they will override properly based on specificity.

```css
#RevenueMTable tbody td
{  
    width: 72px !important;

}

#RevenueMTable tbody td.column0 {
    width: 138px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  #RevenueMTable tbody td:nth-child(2)
  {  
      width: 72px !important;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a brief explanation as to why this solves the OPs problem?

Comment: td:nth-child(2) means the second column if you want to specify the third column it will be like  #RevenueMTable tbody td:nth-child(3) and so on.

Comment: Please update *your answer* with the brief explanation :) On SO, code only answers frequently get flagged for being "Low Quality" and are moderated (hence, why I saw your answer.) Frequently, code-only answers don't provide enough information / context to truly help the user (or future site visitors.)